# Updating a message layout for logging to a textfile using NLog during runtime

Tags: vb.net, debugging, logging, config, nlog

I am currently trying to create a new message layout that I will use to change the default layout during runtime.

Here is the code:

```
Imports NLog

Public Class Class2
    Public filename As String = "C:\Users\hi\Documents\TestLogging.txt"
    Public _logger As NLog.Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(My.Application.Info.AssemblyName)

    Public Sub TestLayoutSwitch()
        Dim newRule As NLog.Config.LoggingRule
        Dim layout As String = "${longdate}|${level}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|Serial No = "
        Dim config As NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration = NLog.LogManager.Configuration

        Dim fileTarget As New NLog.Targets.FileTarget() With {
           .FileName = filename,
           .Layout = layout
        }

        newRule = New Config.LoggingRule("*", fileTarget)
        config.LoggingRules.Add(newRule)
        LogManager.Configuration = config
        _logger.Factory.ReconfigExistingLoggers()

        _logger.Warn("TestWarn")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Basically, what I want to do is to add "Serial No =" to the end of my log message at runtime but it is currently not working.

[image: Picture]

In the picture I show how it currently looks like.

What I actually want it to look like is like the following:

```
2019-07-29 13:26:15.2767|Warn|ConsoleTestLogger|TestWarn|SerialNo. = (value goes here later)
```

I currently have no errors in my code, but the only thing is the layout is not being changed when I want it to.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I think you should read https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/LogEvent-Context-Information

Comment: That link doesn't have what I am looking for, which is updating the layout at runtime.

Comment: Is it the idea to update the layout every log write? That's not supported in NLog (for at least performance reasons), you need one of the context options described in the link

Comment: @Julian Can you please post an answer stating definitively that this is impossible , I need to make this case with my boss.

Comment: I'm not saying something is impossible. At lot is possible in NLog! I think this is a http://xyproblem.info/. I would recommend to edit the post and try to explain more what you need and focus less on the not working code.